# handle Multi touch and mouse events with single event -WPF

Tags: wpf

I need to provide panning and zooming capabilities to my image in WPF. I have followed the below link and it works fine for Touch screen based system.
[Multi touch with WPF](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_multi_touch.htm) . But what it doesn't work with ,mouse events. such as scrolling the mouse wheel to zoom or rotating the image using mouse. below are my questions?

1. Is there any possibilities to achieve both mouse and touch events by means single event?
2. IF yes how to do that?
3. If it is not possible, Why?

Answer (score 1):

There are no such Common thing except the click events like MouseLeftButtonDown,MouseDown ... You have to Implement your own logic for Touch and Mouse Based Interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are not the same

Take a touch and drag, and a click and drag, superficially the same

But a click can be left, right, middle, special, it can be multiple buttons at once, none of that has anything to do with a touch

likewise a touch pinch has no meaning as mouse scroll wheel event

So you need to capture the different Events and convert them into a meaningful command that the VM can perform